# Livewire 2 Increment Value in database tabel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I am new to laravel & livewire, I am trying to increment the value in database, but I am facing the below error.

**error im getting**

```
TypeError 
Illegal offset type
```

> CODE

```
public $Received_Amount; //this getting input value from numbers example like 100,200,1,3


   public function submit( ) 
    {
      DB::table('users')->where('Id','=', Auth::user()->Id)->increment(['Received_Amount' => $this->Received_Amount]); 
    }
```

> Form

```
 <form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="form-group">
       <div class="form-control-wrap">
         <label>Received Amount <lable style="color:red;">*</lable>
         </label>
         <input type="text" wire:model="Received_Amount" class="form-control form-control-outlined form-control-outlined">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl btn-primary">SAVE APPLICATION</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass an array to the increment method, but it expects a string and a number like this:

```
increment('Received_Amount', $this->Received_Amount)
```

Comment: i tried above code im passing 500 or 100  or 10 in input but it was giving value "1"   every time i pass i checked in dd()   same value "1",                               
    1 // app\Http\Livewire\User\Entrollment.php:342

Comment: do you pass it directly to the method like this `increment('Received_Amount', 500)` ?
if not try it and look what happens.
either way, it would be useful if you show, how your variable `$Received_Amount` gets its value.

Comment: im not passing like this  increment('Received_Amount', 500), im getting value by input filed i updated my question input filed